# Android language is not changing on Android 6

Tags: android, locale

I am trying to change the language in my app. When user clicks a button, I save the language to sharedpreferences and I call  `super.recreate();`

Then I have this code:

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newBase);
    lng = prefs.getString("mylang", "sk");

    Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
        Locale.setDefault(locale);config.setLocale(locale);
        newBase = newBase.createConfigurationContext(config);

    }  else {Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        newBase.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        newBase.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
}
```

This is working very well on devices >= Android N, but on lower versions the language is not changing.

So the problem is in this part:

```
 else {Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    newBase.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                             newBase.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

I tried to replace `newBase` with `this` or `getApplicationContext()`, but then I have nullpointer exception. But if I leave there newBase, the language is not changing.

Strange thing is, if I remove the whole `attachBaseContext` method, and put the code for old devices to onclick method:

```
 this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                            this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

this way it works on old devices. But I need attachBaseContext there due to deprecation for newer versions. But if I put the `attachBaseContext` back, then it is not working, so I suppose, there is something wrong inside `attachBaseContext` for old androids.

UPDATE:

If I remove `attachBaseContext` and put the code to `onCreate`, then the language is working for old devices, but not for newer androids :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        Locale.setDefault(locale);config.setLocale(locale);
        getBaseContext().createConfigurationContext(config);

    }  else {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Comment: instead of writing the code in `attachBaseContext` write it to `onCreate`

Comment: well, it partially helped, if I put the code to onCreate, the language is working for old devices now, but now it doesn't work for versions N and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I separated the code for versions below N and higher as N:

```
  @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
    }

  private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
       
     ...

        Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
        }

        return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
    }

    private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    private Context updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return context;
    }
```

and then in onCreate I use:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateBaseContextLocale(getBaseContext());
        }
```

This way it works finally for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

First as we discussed, remove `attachBaseContext()` and add its code into `onCreate()`

Then modify the code to get `updateConfiguration()` shared  between old and new versions (above Android-N)

Add below code in `onCreate`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Configuration config = new Configuration(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
    Locale.setDefault(local);
    config.setLocale(local);
    getBaseContext().createConfigurationContext(config);

} else {
    Locale.setDefault(local);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
}

Configuration config = new Configuration();
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: you can't have updateConfiguration out of conditions as it is deprecated for higher versions (for now it will work until it will be removed from higher versions, so I want to avoid using deprecated code). So newer versions must have attachBaseContext and older not. Only this way it is working now.